# How do I store objects in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, object, local-storage

I am trying to set and get items from local storage but when i log the data i get [object Object]

i am trying to get the view of that object something like this {a : v, b : v }...

here is the code :

```
var widgets = localStorage.getItem('widgets');
        if (widgets == null) {
         widgets = {
            widget_lot : '',
            widget_td : '',
            widget_cwo : '',
            widget_vehicles : '',
            widget_take : ''
            };  

            widgets.widget_lot = 0;
            widgets.widget_td = 0;
            widgets.widget_cwo = 1;
            widgets.widget_vehicles = 0;
            widgets.widget_take = 0;

            localStorage.setItem('widgets', widgets);
        }

        console.log(widgets); //Logs "[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Local storage only supports `string` datatype. So you have to

1. Convert it to String before saving to LocalStorage

   ```
   localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(data));
   ```
2. Convert back to JS object, reading from LocalStorage

   ```
   data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key')); //forgot to close
   ```

In case of your code, it should be -

```
var widgets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('widgets'));
```

and

```
localStorage.setItem('widgets', JSON.stringify(widgets));
```

Comment: thanks mate, works like a charm.. i was trying to fiddle with JSON but was getting unexpected error on token o... deleted the localstorage and saved the data gain, so it works now..

Thanks againa

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you mark the answer as accepted. Will help someone else if he/she needs same help ... :)

Comment: a guy from 2021 thank you.@brainlesscoder

Answer (score 2):

You need to stringify the object before storing it to the storage like

```
localStorage.setItem('widgets', JSON.stringify(widgets));
```

[localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) stores the value as string, so when you try to save an object to `toString()` method of the value to be stored is called, since you have a object it will return [object Object]

In the same way, [getItem()](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem) returns a string, to convert it to a object use JSON.parse()

so

```
var widgets = localStorage.getItem('widgets');
console.log('stored', widgets)
if (widgets == null) {
    widgets = {
        widget_lot: '',
        widget_td: '',
        widget_cwo: '',
        widget_vehicles: '',
        widget_take: ''
    };

    widgets.widget_lot = 0;
    widgets.widget_td = 0;
    widgets.widget_cwo = 1;
    widgets.widget_vehicles = 0;
    widgets.widget_take = 0;

    localStorage.setItem('widgets', JSON.stringify(widgets));
} else {
    widgets = JSON.parse(widgets)
}

console.log(widgets); //Logs "[object Object]"
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9tZdJ/)